# Getting garbage values for "*" ASCII

Tags: c

I'm doing a multiplication of two numbers. The * operator is not taken as a valid ASCII value.

main.c

```
  #include <stdio.h>

    extern int add();
    extern int mul();

    main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       char oper;
       oper = (char)argv[2][0];
            printf("\n argv: %d : %d : %d\n",atoi(argv[1]),atoi(argv[2]),atoi(argv[3]));

       if ( oper == '+' )
           printf ("%d\n", add(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[3])));
       if ( oper == '*' )
           printf ("%d\n", mul(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[3])));
    }
```

mul.c

```
int mul (int x, int y)
{
   int ans;
   ans = x * y;
   return (ans);
}
```

Sample output:

```
a@ubuntu:~/a/make$ ./basic 1 + 2

 argv: 1 : 0 : 2
 3 //=> gives the correct answer after addition
a@ubuntu:~/a/make$ ./basic 1 * 2

 argv: 1 : 0 : 0

 //Doesnt output any the answer.
```

Why is the arguments getting junk values and why the multiplication is not done.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that your shell replaces `*` with a list of the files in your current directory.

Any standard shell on linux/mac will do file substitution, and if you don't want that you will need to escape the characters `*` and `?`, like

```
./basic 1 \* 2
```

Comment: `echo *` on Windows begs to differ

Comment: Not necessarily the case on Windows, but definitely true for Unix-ish shells (like the one in use here)

Comment: prefer simple quotation marks to avoid the shell substitution. `echo '*'` or `./basic 1 '*' 2`.

Comment: When in doubt, put your data in a file and read from the file.  This has an advantage that you don't have to repeat typing the same data.  You can also set up automated testing by using a data file.